# Create an API from Apache kafka so that andriod application can get data from it

Tags: android, api, apache-kafka

I am trying to create a Kafka API so that my android application can make a GET request from it to populate table view in it.

My question how I can make a Kafka API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would make it like any other API, honestly

However, you could use existing tools like Confluent REST Proxy as a producer/consumer, or ksqlDB REST API as an interface on top of Kafka Streams tables.

Otherwise, refer the Interactive Queries section of Kafka Streams for other ways to expose RPC later to access StateStore information

Comment: I know how to create Kafka producer/consumer. the issue with me I dont know to make it Kafka REST Proxy. Would you mind referee me to a video tutorial where I can create Kafka REST proxy as consumer?

Comment: Have you looked at the github repo for the Confluent REST proxy? The consumer endpoint is builtin, there's nothing you need to do but install it